# Discount function not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
#Function - Discount for Buy 5 get 1 Free
def Generate_Discount1 ():
       if (entWindow1.get() != ""):
              price = 0.99
              free = 1
              DiscNo =  (int(entWindow1.get())+
                            int(entWindow2.get())+
                            int(entWindow3.get())+
                            int(entWindow4.get())+
                            int(entWindow5.get())+
                            int(entWindow6.get())+
                            int(entWindow7.get())+
                            int(entWindow8.get())+
                            int(entWindow9.get()))
              total_bought = float (price*DiscNo)
              total_free = float (price*free)
              return 0.2 / (total_bought / total_free)
```

I can't get my discount function to work, it's for python 3.4 using tkinter.

This function should give the discount, if a customer bought 5 donuts they would get one free.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Do you get an error message? Do you get unexpected behavior? Also, you should try to make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the code you posted can not be run and debugged by anyone. We have to guess how `totalT`, `stvDicountOne` etc are defined.

Comment: The example code isn't even valid Python (*not quite*). -- I'm sure there's some things missing around ```.get`` and ``.set``; just not sure what :)

Comment: Should `label(...)` be `Label(...)`? Also, what is `set` and `get` supposed to du?

Comment: Please, when posting codes, you have either to post all relevant codes together so we can understand or explain each variable you are using, like this we cannot provide much help as we lose much time in guessing what you are trying to do...not to solve your issue

Comment: Sorry everyone i am new to using this site, i have added a new code that i have been working on as a question i hope that makes better sense.  I have tried to delete this question because it didnt make much sense now i read it through and i am sorry but it wont let me delete now you have commented,

Comment: again sorry i am very thank full for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is how you compute *what I believe* you're after:

**Example:**

```
def discount(p, n, f=0):
    """Calculate discount as a percentage (given as a float)
       given:

       (p)rice
       (n)umber
       (f)ree
    """

    total_bought = float(p * n)
    total_free = float(p * f)

    return 1.0 / (total_bought / total_free)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> discount(1, 5, 1)
0.2  # 20% discount
>>> discount(1, 5, 2)
0.4  # 40% discount
>>> discount(1, 6, 3)
0.5  # 50% discount
>>> discount(1, 6, 6)
1.0  # 100% discount
```

Comment: thank you but where would i input that coding in mine?

Comment: #Function - Discount for Buy 9 get 3 Free
def Generate_Discount2 ():
       if (entWindow1.get() != ""):
              discTwo=3//9-(int(entWindow1.get())+
                            int(entWindow2.get())+
                            int(entWindow3.get())+
                            int(entWindow4.get())+
                            int(entWindow5.get())+
                            int(entWindow6.get())+
                            int(entWindow7.get())+
                            int(entWindow8.get())+
                            int(entWindow9.get()))